# Connection to AWS RedShift (SSL enabled) from Azure ADF IR Linked Services

Tags: azure, ssl, amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect to AWS RedShift from Azure Data Factory Linked Services, after configuring the Redshift credentials, it is giving me `"Connection Timeout Exception"`.

I know where the problem is, I need a help to configure SSL parameter in ADF Linked Services to connect to AWS RedShift.
I am able to connect to AWS RedShift from a VM hosted in our Azure environment using DBeaver by setting SSL = True and SSL Mode=verify-full.

[image]

I need help on how to pass this SSL information from ADF linked Services in order to establish connection with RedShift.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to fix the connection issue by setting below redshift parameter in linked services.

[image]